# Magento SOAP API add a custom column value to the salesOrderInfo and salesOrderList

Tags: sales-order, soap-api-v2

I have added a column 'leadsource' in 'sales_flat_order'. I have to pull this in api . Please help.

Comment: are you able to get other data in soap api ?

Comment: yes, am getting other data in salesOrderInfo. Actually, I couldn't find where is this coming from.